# Codename one image component

Tags: codenameone

What's the best component to include image into the layout?

I found `Label` to do this job. But I've problem with customizing width and height of the image.

This is the android look and feel:

[image]

I'd like to migrate it into CNO.So, I created custom theme to get the backgound gray and margin around container. The layout of container is `TableLayout` set to have 4 columns and 1 row. I'd like to see the content (*image, multiline label, label, image*) autoscale based on parent width and i'd like to defined components width as percentage fraction of the parent.

For now, the first image takes the width and height from icon, which is bigger that is needed. It takes a bit more space that i intend to. How can i change the image size without resizing the image resource?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default label has a small amount of padding/margin around it (and so do most components).

You can just test that this is the problem by using `label.setUIID("Container")` which always has 0 padding and margin (by default).

You can also edit your app theme using the designer tool and add a new UIID for Label where you can override padding/margin with 0.

Comment: But is there a way how to change width and height of the components? How it actually works? Is the width and height fixed or it is somehow variable? It is based on pixels or percentage or points? Can you explain?

Comment: I suggest you check out the How Do I? video on layout managers http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i.html the width and height are in pixels but if you change them the layout manager will override your changes. You need to define the logical flow so the components will arrange correctly on all OS's/orientations.